# The Temple Of Demdarr, God Of Puzzling (Part 1)

Tags: cipher, pattern

### Prologue

You're a adventurous treasure hunter that just entered the first room of "*The temple of Demdarr*", an ancient temple in the arabian desert. It is rumoured that you have to pass three tests (three rooms) in order to reach the much sighed-for treasure. No-one has ever even dared to take a step into the temple, as you end up dead if you make the slightest mistake. But of course you are confident in yourself and will try it. You enter the first room and encounter three 10x10 tilings. You realise each section has it's own rule or pattern. Now you just have to figure out which tilings are safe, and which are not in order to get to the next room. (Each unsafe tiling only will be triggered if an/multiple object/s over 1kg (2,2 lbs) is/are on it. You will die if this happens to an unsafe tiling and if you are inside the temple. And no, there is no way to survive it :) (you can't run that fast and you are 259,2 meters away from the entry) )

---

### Rules

**Movement:** In this room you  have to bear in mind that you can only move one or two steps horizontally/vertically, and only one step diagonaly.

Visualization (You can only go on green squares):

[image]

A **good answer** must contain all the tilings that are safe, wheter it's visualized in an image or you just list them like $(5,2)$ (which would be the square at the 5th column and 2nd row). Or, wrote/described as a vector, 5 to the right and 2 downwards. (from the top left)

---

### The Room

*If you have problems reading this or you want a more basic version, **[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWcsM.png).***

*Please also note that there are 4 mistakes in the bottom grid (thanks to Gordon K). False are R3C9, R4C7, R7C4, R8C7, R9C3.*
*Also, in the middle grid, R8C3 and R3C4 should be "<".*

*(The door to the next room is at the top, so you start at the bottom)*

[image]

---

### Hints

Hint 1 for bottom Grid:

> The actual clue is "r*f mod 12 = 0". Don't interpret anything in r and f, these are random variable names because I don't want to give away too much. Why L = 12? You will know that if you find out the pattern in this grid ;)

Hint 1 for middle Grid:

> Look at the title of the post

Hint 2 for middle Grid:

> Actually, this is more of a clarification (I wouldn't have posted another hint so quickly). This grid doesn't have a pattern, although I stated before that every grid has one.

Hint 1 for top Grid:

> There is more than one pattern in this grid

Comment: Well, first of all, you're dead, because there will never be a way for you to prevent your dust from touching any of the wrong tiles. You did say "(You die if anything touches a wrong one)".

Comment: @Kingrames I had problems phrasing this because people would've written anwers like: "Just throw a stone and see which ones are safe"... I'll look if I can rephrase this properly... With no loop-holes (There will probably always be some)

Comment: Don't worry. It's not an entirely serious response, I just wanted to get it out of the way. ;)

Comment: The dark red (or light pink on the text version) are what separates each room from one another? And do they have tiles, or no?

Comment: @Raystafarian This puzzle and the three 10x10 grids are all inside the first room. The light pink parts are the clues for the grids. So the bottom light pink part contains the clues for the first 10x10 grid. The light pinks parts are not the tilings I was talking about, they are areas where you can stand safe. When I say "tiling" I mean the darker squares (in the alternative image)

Comment: The door hasn't closed behind you, has it?

Comment: @JoeZ. Feel free to leave the temple :P

Comment: Great, because the Temple of Quetzalcoatl traps you inside. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a _complete_ ripoff :P

Comment: @Raystafarian There are unnecessary safe squares in some grids, but there aren't multiple paths through any grid. (Assuming you don't visit the same square twice)

Comment: Then I'm way off using ASCII codes and mod (factor of 76) = 0.

Comment: Hmm, if the first hint would be `mod X = 0` I would have a solution for the first part. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Sleafar I added hints to the question, I think that will make it clearer what the bottom hint means.

Comment: There are 5 'mistakes' in the bottom grid. Are they deliberate? [R3C9, R4C7, R7C4, R8C7, R9C3]

Comment: @JoeZ. I actually just realised now that you've made a similar puzzle/story/temple. Sorry! I only looked if PSE contained a similar title... I didn't mean to copy you, in fact I never heard of it as I'm fairly new to this stie/to puzzling :/

Comment: It's alright, I don't actually think you're a ripoff of mine. You're totally okay doing this.

Comment: Note to self: *change username to Demdarr*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer to the middle grid:**

> We note that the sequence
>    `$! (= {\ ]- ?' }[ ;. *# ~/ _" )+ <^ |>`
>
> contains each character exactly once and is 26 characters long (not
> counting the spaces). This suggests that the characters map to the
> alphabet, we transform the grid
>
>  `W I I U H L N N Y P
>  G O W R S W Z I X G
>  L X N E R A U N K Y
>  I J U Y C Y Q Y O Z
>  F S C O K D C K F I
>  G I W S M Z S U W S
>  Y H U Q L X Y B Z C
>  Y G E P E N G I B H
>  O K T D C H X Q O K
>  O U I Q Y S W W S C`
>
> We now need to find our way through that, luckily, the title indicates
> the name of our puzzling god: `Demdarr`. We can so find the way that
> leads through the middle grid (marked as bold)

---

**Answer to the last grid:**

> The grid is actually divided into four parts: The top left, the top right, the bottom left, the bottom right.
>  The operations are applied to the row and column of each field. So for the top left 5x5 grid we have `col+row=H`. The top right 5x5 is `col-row=D`, the bottom left 5x5 grid is `col*row=RD`, the bottom right 5x5 is `col mod row=A`. The results of the operations yield the number in each field, and the field is safe if it agrees with the given result.
> The only exception to this is the bottom left grid, here a field is safe if the value mod 26 is either `18`/`R` or `4`/`D` 
> So the correct path through the whole grid is
>
>  `2  3  4  5  6  | 5 6 7 8 9
>  3  4  5  6  7  | 4 5 6 7 8
>  4  5  6  7  8  | 3 4 5 6 7
>  5  6  7  8  9  | 2 3 4 5 6
>  6  7  8  9  10 | 1 2 3 4 5
>  --------------------------
>  6  12 18 24 30 | 0 1 2 3 4
>  7  14 21 28 35 | 6 0 1 2 3
>  8  16 24 32 40 | 6 7 0 1 2
>  9  18 27 36 45 | 6 7 8 0 1
>  10 20 30 40 50 | 6 7 8 9 0`

Comment: Nice, only one grid to go now! I hope one of you two gets it, because then I could just give the green tick to the one that solved 2/3 grids, which would be fair.

Comment: @LuxxMiner, the only thing I can't interpret is `* = RD`, everything else I think I found out.

Comment: If you are on the right track, this might help: Interpret it as `* = R, D` or `* = R and D`. **No operation** between R and D **is needed** (like +, -, * ...)

Comment: @LuxxMiner, updated the answer with my solution to the last grid

Comment: 30 is 4/D mod 26, I guess.

Comment: @f Ahhh, nice catch

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the bottom grid:

> Converting the grid of numbers to their positions in the alphabet, the pattern gives a regular times table grid, however there are five letters in the grid which do not comply with modulo 26 conversion. I'll ignore them for now as they have no bearing on the cells required for the solution.
>
>  `1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
>  2    4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
>  3    6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
>  4    8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
>  5    10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
>  6    12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
>  7    14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
>  8    16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
>  9    18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
>  10   20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100`
>
> Applying `mod(x,12)` to these (as L is the 12th letter of the alphabet) gives
>
>
>  `1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
>  2    4   6   8   10  0   2   4   6   8
>  3    6   9   0   3   6   9   0   3   6
>  4    8   0   4   8   0   4   8   0   4
>  5    10  3   8   1   6   11  4   9   2
>  6    0   6   0   6   0   6   0   6   0
>  7    2   9   4   11  6   1   8   3   10
>  8    4   0   8   4   0   8   4   0   8
>  9    6   3   0   9   6   3   0   9   6
>  10   8   6   4   2   0   10  8   6   4`
>
>  Every zero is safe, but the bold ones are the path you should take.

Comment: This is the correct answer for this grid, good job!